# Close button in jsp page not working after response is redirected from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Submit button on my jsp(Welcome.jsp) page upon which I send the request to myservlet(Import Parts). I do some validation in servlet and upon failing on the validation I redirect user to the error.jsp page which give a suitable message. This error.jsp also has a close button which does not work after I forward the response to error.jsp.

If I directly launch the error.jsp in browser and try to click the close button, it works.

```
// Below is the piece of code written in my Servlet on doPost() method which perform some validation and upon failing the validation check redirects user to error.jsp page.

if(!UserDetails.checkValidUser(asession))  //a Validation method returning true or false
            {
                logger.info("User do not have necessary role");
                request.setAttribute("error", EMSImportConstants.NO_PRIVILEGE_USER_ERR_MESSAGE);
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Error.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }

//Below is my error.jsp page code

<% 
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path;
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error in EMS BOM Import</title>
        <link href="<%=basePath %>/css/netapps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" class="borderless">
<form method="post" action="Error.jsp">

 <center>
            <div id="banner">
                <div id="logo"></div>

                <div id="rightbg">
                    <div id="bannerTitle"><br>EMS BOM Import</div>
                </div>
                <div id="bannerImage"> </div>
            </div>
</center>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<center>
<font size = "2px" color="red">
<%=request.getAttribute("error") %>
</font>
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="button" value="Close"  onclick="window.close();"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>


I click on close button but nothing happens.
```

Comment: try getting rid of the if in your servlet to see the behaviour. what kind of message dou you get?

Comment: If statement is not causing a problem here because the behavior remains same. In case I remove if, I will be redirected to my error.jsp page on which the close button still don't work.
However if I directly run the error.jsp page and try to click on close button, it closes the browser window but the same button does not work when I forward from my servlet to this error.jsp.

Comment: This is still unanswered, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a **form**, to submit the details, the `input` type should be `submit` but not `button`. Change your code this way. It should work :)

```
<form>
  <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Close" onclick="window.close();" /></td>
</form>
```

Comment: The flow of the code is -- Welcome.jsp - > User clicks Submit button on welcome.jsp and the request goes to Servlet. -> I call a method from servlet which returns true/false-> On false I redirect user to error.jsp page which contains close button.
I do not understand why I need submit button in error.jsp, since I am not sending any request from error.jsp page.